# Mapeamentos em .NET CORE, Fluent API - propriedade .HasForeignKey com erro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Boa tarde!

Estou começando desenvolver um sistema em .net, meio que na marra, então to aprendendo conforme vou construindo, mas alguns erros ainda não estão claros para mim

Tenho o seguinte código:
        //classe barco

```
    public string Nome { get; private set; }

    public bool Ativo { get; private set; }

    public string SapId { get; private set; }

    public string Resumo { get; private set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; private set; }

    public Nullable<int> CapacidadeAgua { get; private set; }

    public Nullable<int> CapacidadeOleo { get; private set; }

    public Nullable<int> Velocidade { get; private set; }

    //Chave estrangeira
    public Guid CategoriaBarcoID { get; private set; }
     //Chave estrangeira
    public Guid TipoOperacaoID { get; private set; }



    //Entity Framework propriedades de Navegação
    public virtual CategoriaBarco CategoriaBarco { get; private set; }

    public virtual TipoOperacao TipoOperacao { get; private set; }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class CategoriaBarco : Entity<CategoriaBarco>
{

    public CategoriaBarco(Guid id, Guid BarcoId, string nome, bool ativo)
    {
        Id = id;
        Nome = nome;
        Ativo = ativo;
    }

    //Construtor para o Entityframework
    protected CategoriaBarco()
    {

    }

    public string Nome { get; private set; }

    public bool Ativo { get; private set; }

    //Chave estrangeira
    public Guid BarcoId { get; set; }


    //Entity Framework Propeidades de Navegação
    public virtual ICollection<Barco> Barcos { get; private set; }



//mapeamento entre a classe Barco e CategoriaBarco
modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
           .HasOne(b => b.CategoriaBarco)
           .WithMany(c => c.Barcos)
           .HasForeignKey(b => b.CategoriaBarcoID)
           .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
            .HasOne(b => b.TipoOperacao)
            .WithMany(b => b.barcos)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.TipoOperacaoID)
            .IsRequired();

       //Mapeamento entre CategoriabBarco e Barcos
      //Código com Erro
          modelBuilder.Entity<CategoriaBarco>()
           .HasMany(c => c.Barcos)
           .WithOne(b => b.CategoriaBarco)
           .HasForeignKey (b => b.BarcoID )
           .IsRequired();
```

Por algum motivo eu não consigo fazer esse relacionamento da CategoriaBarco com o Barco. Pelo pouco q entendi quando eu faço o .HasForeignKey (b => b.BarcoID ) ele não deveria encontrar a chave estrangeira da classe Barco que está na Classe categoria?

Como poderia fazer esse relacionamento onde, uma categoria tem muitos barcos, mas um barco só tem uma categoria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na sua classe CategoriaBarco, como é uma relação 1:N, a sua classe não precisa ter a propriedade BarcoID, pois se ela tiver, quer dizer que você está dizendo que Categoria tem somente um barco (1:1).

Retire a propriedade BarcoID da classe CategoriaBarco e na configuração da sua classe retire essa parte:

```
//Mapeamento entre CategoriabBarco e Barcos
//Código com Erro
modelBuilder.Entity<CategoriaBarco>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Barcos)
    .WithOne(b => b.CategoriaBarco)
    .HasForeignKey (b => b.BarcoID )
    .IsRequired();
```

Comment: Mas então, na classe CategoriaBarco eu tenho essa propriedade:  public virtual ICollection<Barco> Barcos { get; private set; }, que seria a coleção de barcos que uma categoria poderia ter. Esse BarcoID seria a chave estrangeira da classe barco, é só uma propiedade do Tipo Guid

Comment: Mas está errado cara, cada barco tem o id, em um relacionamento 1:N a FK fica na entidade filha (barco). Percebe que, se você tem uma lista de barcos, não faz sentido você ter o ID só de 1?

Comment: Entendi, como eu ja fiz o mapeamento  1:N 

HasOne(b => b.CategoriaBarco)
           .WithMany(c => c.Barcos)
           .HasForeignKey(b => b.CategoriaBarcoID) 

ja fica entendido que a CategoriaBarco ja tem muitos Barcos e a chave estrangeira que está na classe Barco, vai fazer identificação.

Comment: Exatamente, no Entity você só precisa configurar uma das entidades quando se trata de relacionamentos, claro que há exceções, mas nos casos comuns esse é o passo. :) Caso a resposta tenha ajudado, marque a resposta como aceita, para que outras pessoas possam se beneficiar da resposta